# OpenVPN : Working with TCP but not with UDP

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, udp

I am trying to connect Raspberry Pi as a client to OpenVPN server(Ubuntu 14.04.3).
Following is my server and client side configuration

```
# server.conf
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append openvpn.log
verb 5

# client.ovpn
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 10.1.2.12 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert pi2.crt
key pi2.key
ns-cert-type server
log-append openvpn.log
verb 5
```

On client side, I get this log "Initialization Sequence Completed." But I can't ping from client to server by `ping 10.8.0.1` or vice-versa.

If I change `proto tcp` on both ends, then it works perfectly fine.

To troubleshoot the problem, I did following things.

1. Tested if my network is capable of handling UDP traffic by

   on server
   `nc -l -u 1194`

   on client
   `nc -u 10.1.2.12 1194`

   I was able to communicate to server from client and vice-versa.
2. Lower the mtu by adding following configuration in both ends

   `tun-mtu 1000
   fragment 900
   mssfix`
3. Changed UDP port to some higher value, like 25000

But still I am not able solve this issue. Any help will be appreciated.
[Client-Server logs](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_XxQm6n7m4la1VPczdoNXM2NGs)

Comment: Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a **business environment**. See: http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic. PS. Your logs are almost useless when you present logs from too short period before killing client thus we're unable to determine what's happen: if you killed your client process intentionally or if timeout occurred because lack of communication.

Comment: I stopped both client and server intentionally coz as soon as initialization process completed, i wasn't able to ping.

Comment: You should wait at least two timeout times and then kill it. That'd show if there's communication problem or configuration one.

Comment: The enthusiast nature of the RPi makes them not topical here.

Answer (score -1):

From OpenVPN manual:

```
--topology mode
Configure virtual addressing topology when running in --dev tun mode.
This directive has no meaning in --dev tap mode, which always uses a
subnet topology.

If you set this directive on the server, the --server and --server-bridge
directives will automatically push your chosen topology setting to
clients as well. This directive can also be manually pushed to clients.
Like the --dev directive, this directive must always be compatible
between client and server.

mode can be one of:

**net30** -- Use a point-to-point topology, by allocating one /30 subnet
per client. This is designed to allow point-to-point semantics when some
or all of the connecting clients might be Windows systems. This is the
default on OpenVPN 2.0.
```

From your client's OpenVPN logs:
Line 308:

```
Mon Aug 29 20:33:54 2016 us=826190 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.6 peer 10.8.0.5
```

Hint: you're "pinging" wrong addresses.

Hint2: What's firewall state?

Hint3: Did you enabled IPv4 forwarding by: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` ?

Comment: server's OpenVPN IP address is `10.8.0.1` so I think, I should be able to do `ping 10.8.0.1` from client system. Right ?

Comment: As you use **net30** topology which is default for tun device your server' address will change for each client. Use `ifconfig` and `route -n` to determine it.

Comment: This is output of ifconfig `tun0 inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255   UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500`

Comment: Please add `ifconfig` from both client and server, and also `route -n`. Give yourself a favor and switch to `topology subnet` in server's config file.

Comment: If you answer less than topical questions, you are implicitly encouraging them.

Comment: I am stupidly thinking that he'll remember for next time.